# Crystal reports application expects parameters to be provided manually

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am working on windows vb.net application with crystal reports.

I have followed the below procedure to pass a string value to report.

> 1.Open Field Explorer window in Crystal report.
>
> 2.Go to Parameter Fields.
>
> 3.Right Click on "Parameter Fields" Click on "New"
>
> 4.In the pop-up window give a Name for your parameter and give its Data Type.Name is myparameter1and Data Type is String.
>
> 5.A parameter field[paraFromDate] will be added under Parameter Fields...Drag this field to your report and place where you want to
>   show your textbox value.
>
> 6.Now in the code behind file write the following code to pass your TextBox value to this Crystal report parameter field.

```
Private Sub btnShowCustomer_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowCustomer.Click
   Try

            Dim cr As New rptDatewiseCustomerReport
           cr.SetParameterValue("paraFromDate","10-9-2015")

   Catch ex As Exceptio
   MessageBox.Show("Error")
   End Try
End Sub
```

program run successfully, but when I open the report, it ask to pass the value of parameter manually.

It supposed to pass through code.

What I am missing ?

[image]

Comment: Please put complete code listing

Comment: There is another option that you may have missed. It says, "Prompt parameter", I am assuming it is set to True.